# How to test if a value is a key of an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am very new to Spark and Scala, and I want to test if a value is a key from an RDD.

The data I have is like this:

> RDD data: key -> value
>
> RDD stat: key -> statistics

What I want to do is to filter all the key-value pairs in data that has the key in stat.

My general idea is to convert the keys of an RDD into a set, then test if a value belongs to this set?

Are there better approaches, and how to convert the keys of an RDD into a set using Scala?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lookup`

```
def lookup(key: K): List[V]
```

> Return the list of values in the RDD for key key. This operation is
>   done efficiently if the RDD has a known partitioner by only searching
>   the partition that the key maps to.

You asked -

> What I want to do is to filter all the key-value pairs in data that
>   has the key in stat.

I think you should `join` by key instead of doing a `lookup`.

```
join(otherDataset, [numTasks])
```

> When called on datasets of type (K, V) and (K, W), returns a dataset
>   of (K, (V, W)) pairs with all pairs of elements for each key. Outer
>   joins are supported through leftOuterJoin, rightOuterJoin, and
>   fullOuterJoin.

.

> "close over an RDD inside another RDD."

Basically using an RDD inside the transformations (in this case `filter`) of another RDD.
Nesting of one RDD inside another is not allowed in Spark.

Comment: Thanks, but I got a lot of error message when running this: val filtered_data = data.filter(x => (filtered_variance.lookup(x._1).size > 0))

Comment: Are `data` and `filtered_variance` both `RDD`s ? If yes then you can *close* over an `RDD` inside another `RDD`.

Comment: Yes, they are both RDDs. Not sure what do you mean by "close over an RDD inside another RDD."